# Oracle RAC VIP issue

Tags: oracle, rac

I have a two node RAC setup where my scan ips are registered in DNS and my public Ips are also registered in the dns. Now while connecting from my windows machine through oracle client in sql developer im getting connection time out error and network adapter error. 
My question is that should I register my VIP also in dns and will that resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes you have to register VIPs in DNS. When you connect to scan IPs you are being redirected to one of the node's VIP. Priv IPs are used for nodes interconnect.

Comment: Are you using GNS or no?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember when I investigated RAC you need to add the VIP addresses to the DNS.

Comment: But why is it needed in dns? It talks between the nodes right.

Comment: How do you define the connection? IP address or name? When it is name you need to put it in DNS or in the hosts file.

Comment: I have put it in DNS. Im still facing sql developer issues though.

Comment: What is the result of `tnsping` to the database? What is the content of the `tnsnames.ora`? I never implemented RAC and I never used sql developer (do you use the latest version?) so I do not know if it needs something special to connect to a RAC database.

Comment: Tnsping works even too. Im getting struck somewhere. Unsure where. Tnsnames is ok since im able to connect it from the server.

Comment: Do you use sql developer on the server?

Comment: On my local pc yes.

Comment: Do not understand. You can connect to the RAC database from the server. Right? You run sql developer from another PC. Right? If so: Can you do a tnsping from the local PC but not sql server?

Comment: Ping tnsping telnet everything from my local pc to the db server is working fine. When i use sql developer from my local pc to connect to the rac db using basic connection it fails.

Comment: Strange. In sql developer you see the RAC database in the selection? Do you sqlplus installed? Does that works? I am afraid I cannot be of any more help.

Comment: I get it mate. Thanks for the help. Hope it resolves soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this two node setup on Linux servers? Are you able to ping the target server through hostname? Once while I was testing a two node RAC running on Virtualbox, I had to add hostname resolution so that the client could communicate with the SCAN ips and resolve them.

If that's the problem, edit the C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and add the ip and hostnames for SCAN resolution.

Ex.:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.56.91    rac-scan.localdomain    rac-scan
192.168.56.92    rac-scan.localdomain    rac-scan
192.168.56.93    rac-scan.localdomain    rac-scan
```

Comment: Nope. Not working.

Comment: Ping is working.